# How to select multiple audio and/or video files in mobile device using xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am writing audio player in Xamarin, I want to create a playlist and save. To create playlist, I want to select audio/video files. I come to know that there is no FileUpload kind of control in Xamarin.

I'm referring Jason's media plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin , I want to use this plugin or any other plugin for creating playlist. I don't know how to configure/change to load audio/video files.

I have added nuget package and trying to configure below information:

### Android Current Activity Setup

This plugin uses the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md) to get access to the current Android Activity. Be sure to complete the full setup if a MainApplication.cs file was not automatically added to your application. Please fully read through the [Current Activity Plugin Documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md). At an absolute minimum you must set the following in your Activity's OnCreate method:

`csharp
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;`

==========================
I know the project I have created is not Xamarin.Android, it is simple .NET 2.0 Core project for mobile application.

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: Added more information into question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm referring Jason's media plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin , I want to use this plugin or any other plugin for creating playlist.

After you added NuGet package, you need to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions and add `Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;` in OnCreate method. Also need override `OnRequestPermissionsResult()` method.

Here is the code:

```
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions; 

namespace selectmultipleaudio
{
    [Activity(Label = "selectmultipleaudio", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button.Click += Button_ClickAsync;
        }

        private async void Button_ClickAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var crossMedia = CrossMedia.Current;
            var media =  await crossMedia.PickVideoAsync();               
        }            

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

And you could use intent to select multiple video file. For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{      
    var videoIntent = new Intent(
        Intent.ActionPick);
    videoIntent.SetType("video/*");
    videoIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
    videoIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    ((Activity)this).StartActivityForResult(
        Intent.CreateChooser(videoIntent, "Select videos"), 0);
}


protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{           
    if (data.ClipData != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.ClipData.ItemCount; i++)
        {

            var video = data.ClipData.GetItemAt(i);
            Uri videouri = video.Uri;
            var path = videouri.Path;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Uri videouri = data.Data;
        var path = videouri.Path;
    }
}
```